# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method error in MVC5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi i  have one view called **DailyVisitReport**. In that view i have two field called **FromDate** and **toDate**. if i select the FromDate and ToDate depends upon the date it shows the table with data in the same view (like partial view).

Now FromDate and ToDate date Format in jquery is "dd-M-y"(01-Mar-16)

In Db also i changed the Date format to (01-Mar-16 STRING).

**My Model(VisitorsViewModel)**

```
public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
public ICollection<View_VisitorsForm> Visits { get; set; }
```

**My Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult GetDatesfromFromDateToDate(string fromDate, string toDate)
{
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; 
    var fromdt = Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate);
    var  todt = Convert.ToDateTime(toDate);
    List<View_VisitorsForm> VisitCount = (from v in db.View_VisitorsForm where DateTime.ParseExact(v.VisitingDate,"dd-M-y", provider) >= fromdt && DateTime.ParseExact(v.VisitingDate,"dd-M-y",provider) <= todt select v).ToList();
    VisitorsViewModel visitotsVM = new VisitorsViewModel();
    visitotsVM.Visits = VisitCount;
    return PartialView("_Visitors", visitotsVM);
}
```

Now I select the `FromDate` and `ToDate` it show the error which is mention below

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)'
>   method

I cant able to convert that `v.VisitingDate` to `DateFormat` from string format .

I tried `Convert.ToDateTime` and `Convert.ToParse` all things. still I'm getting error. please any one understand my issue and help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why don't you just use `v.VisitingDate.Date` to compare with `fromdt.Date`?

Comment: ok i have a try and let you know dii

Comment: *In Db also i changed the Date format to (01-Mar-16 STRING)* Wrong. You should store your dates as `DateTime` corresponding db type, not as strings.

Comment: before in db the date format in db is 2016-02-03 00:00:00.000 i conver this to 01-Mar-16 by Replace(Convert(varchar(50), vf.VisitingDate,6), ' ', '-')As VisitingDate  as per front end

Answer (score 3):

All the operations inside a Linq to Entities query are converted to sql.
DateTime.Parse cannot be translated to sql thus the error.

Perform the parse outside the `where` to solve specifically that problem but, more generally, you should make `VisitingDate` a DateTime property too.

Comment: how to do that any example query ??

Answer (score 1):

The property `VisitingDate`should be of type `DateTime`to avoid these struggles. Do not compare datetime values by using string mishmash, use `DateTime` types.

The where condition would then look like

```
where v.VisitingDate.HasValue ?
    v.VisitingDate.Value >= fromdt && v.VisitingDate.Value <= todt
  : 
    ... // put a condition here when visiting date has no value in DB
```

Also heres a list of supported / unsupported methods in LINQ to SQL, i assume the same goes for LINQ to Entities: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386970.aspx

Therefore you cannot use Parse....

Comment: In Model DateOnly in db only string before in db the date format in db is 2016-02-03 00:00:00.000 i conver this to 01-Mar-16 by                                 Replace(Convert(varchar(50), vf.VisitingDate,6), ' ', '-')As VisitingDate

Comment: Show me the definition of `VisitingDate` of your model, you dont really need to use string replace stuff here. All you need is to first convert incoming parameters to DateTimes (as you already did) and then ensure that the DB column you are comparing to is also of type DateTime.

Comment: public Nullable<System.DateTime> VisitingDate { get; set; }

Comment: @Susan See my edit *The where condition would then look like...*